# Ruby case statement with multiple variables using an Array

Tags: ruby, arrays, case, equals

I'd like to compare multiple variables for a case statement, and am currently thinking overriding the case equals operator (===) for Array is the best way to do it.  Is this the best way?

Here is an example use case:

```
def deposit_apr deposit,apr 
  # deposit: can be nil or 2 length Array of [nil or Float, String]  
  # apr: can be nil or Float     
  case [deposit,apr] 
    when [[Float,String],Float] 
      puts "#{deposit[0]} #{deposit[1]}, #{apr*100.0}% APR"
    when [[nil,String],Float] 
      puts "#{apr*100.0}% APR on deposits greater than 100 #{deposit[1]}"
    when [[Float,String],nil] 
      puts "#{deposit[0]} #{deposit[1]}"
    else 
      puts 'N/A' 
  end
end
```

The only problem is the Array case equals operator doesn't apply the case equal to the elements of the Array.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > deposit_apr([656.00,'rupees'],0.065)
N/A
```

It will if I override, but am not sure what I'd be breaking if I did:

```
class Array
  def ===(other)
    result = true
    self.zip(other) {|bp,ap| result &&= bp === ap}
    result
  end
end
```

Now, it all works:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > deposit_apr([656.00,'rupees'],0.065)
656.0 rupees, 6.5% APR
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 9):

I found this question because I was looking to run a `case` statement on multiple variables, but, going through the following, came to the conclusion that needing to compare multiple variables might suggest that a different approach is needed. (I went back to my own code with this conclusion, and found that even a Hash is helping me write code that is easier to understand.)

Gems today use ["no monkey patching" as a selling point](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#clean). Overriding an operator is probably not the right approach. Monkey patching is great for experimentation, but it's too easy for things to go awry.

Also, there's a lot of type-checking. In a language that is designed for Duck Typing, this clearly indicates the need for a different approach. For example, what happens if I pass in integer values instead of floats? We'd get an 'N/A', even though that's not likely what we're looking for.

You'll notice that the example given in the question is difficult to read. We should be able to find a way to represent this logic more clearly to the reader (and to the writer, when they revisit the code again in a few months and have to puzzle out what's going on).

And finally, since there are multiple numbers with associated logic, it seems like there's at least one [value object](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/)-type class (`Deposit`) that wants to be written.

For cleanliness, I'm going to assume that a `nil` APR can be considered a 0.0% APR.

```
class Deposit
  def initialize(amount, unit='USD', options={})
    @amount = amount.to_f # `nil` => 0.0
    @unit   = unit.to_s   # Example assumes unit is always present
    @apr    = options.fetch(:apr, 0.0).to_f # `apr: nil` => 0.0
  end
end
```

Once we have our Deposit object, we can implement the print logic without needing `case` statements at all.

```
class Deposit

  # ... lines omitted

  def to_s
    string = "#{@amount} #{@unit}"
    string << ", #{@apr * 100.0}% APR" if @apr > 0.0
    string
  end
end

d = Deposit.new(656.00, 'rupees', apr: 0.065)
d.to_s
# => "656.0 rupees, 6.5% APR"

e = Deposit.new(100, 'USD', apr: nil)
e.to_s
# => "100.0 USD"

f = Deposit.new(100, 'USD')
f.to_s
# => "100.0 USD"
```

**Conclusion**: If you're comparing multiple variables in a case statement, use that as a smell to suggest a deeper design issue. Multiple-variable `case`s might indicate that there's an object that wants to be created.

Answer (score 2):

If you are worried about breaking something by changing `Array` behavior, and certainly that's a reasonable worry, then just put your revised operator in a subclass of Array.

Answer (score -1):

it's definitely not the best way. even more - you should not redefine methods of standart classes as core functionality may depend on it - have fun debugging then.

defensive style is nice(with lot of type checks and whatnot) but it usually hurts performance *and* readability.

if you know that you will not pass anything else than bunch of floats and strings to that method - why do you need all those checks for?

IMO use exception catching and fix the source of problem, don't try to fix the problem somewhere in the middle